# создать из массива массив javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

у меня get приходят данные; каждая данная data[i] 
выглядит вот так, а как получить например отдельно 30 или 28, то есть данные в данных после запятой?

```
[ 1517850000000,
      '30',
      '31',
      '28',
      '29',
      '50',
      1517853599999,
      '5001',
      400,
      '40',
      '20',
      '0' ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> data[i][1] === '30';
>
> data[i][3] === '28';

ты это имеешь ввиду?

Comment: да ) спасибо, не знал, что так можно

Comment: @Redbeard, да не надо говорить спасибо, для этого есть галочка выбрать ответ. Пожалуйста выберите ответ решенным.